# installing Webseal infront of IHS Server

Tags: webseal

How to configure Webseal. We couldnt find any download link.

Also our setup is like we have 7 different IBM applications running behind one IHS server. Also we have to configure one webseal server infron of the IHS reverse proxy server. How to make it

Comment: we are aware that we wont get support from IBM for clm applications with Webseal as reverse proxy. But we have to deploy our clm applications on an environment where webseal is already using as a reverse proxy.

So we came into a decision that, we will configure clm applications with IHS as reverse proxy and then will  make this to run behind webseal.

So our architecture plan is like 

Webseal --> IHS ---> CLM appications with Liberty.

We can configure the applications with IHS reverse proxy. But we are not sure that how to make this setup behind a webseal and where we need your help

Comment: any suggestions. Highly appreciated